# How to reject a request on AWS API Gateway if it contains unknown query parameters?

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger, aws-api-gateway, openapi

I am using API Gateway integrated with OpenAPI 3.0 to validate incoming requests before sending them to Lambda. API Gateway is validating the request body as I expect based on the OAS request schema definition. I want API Gateway to either strip unknown query parameters from the request, or throw a 400 error.

Currently, it is ignoring any additional parameters in the request and sending them on to the backend Lambda. This can be done in OpenAPI for request body using `additionalProperties: false` property but there is no similar property for disallowing unknown query parameters. In my OpenAPI spec I tried setting

```
x-amazon-apigateway-request-validators:
  body-and-params:
    validateRequestBody: true
    validateRequestParameters: true
```

but it looks like API Gateway only does positive validation on parameters that are flagged as required.